# Почему слетает авторизация?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Подскажите, поставил прокси

```
axios: {
    proxy: true,
    debug: false,
    browserBaseURL: '/api',
  },

  proxy: {
    '/api': {
      target: process.env.API_URL,
    },
  },
```

и при обновлении страницы, слетает авторизация и перекидывает на страницу логина, при повторном логине, ничего не происходит, но данные вытаскивает из api?

Была ли у кого такая проблема? auth-next v5

```
auth: {
    cookie: false,
    strategies: {
      'laravelJwt': {
        provider: 'laravel/jwt',
        url: '/v1',
        redirect: {
          login: '/login',
          logout: '/login',
          callback: '/',
          home: '/',
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/auth/login',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'token',
          },
          logout: { url: '/auth/logout', method: 'post' },
          refresh: { url: '/auth/refresh', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: '/auth/me', method: 'post' },
        },
        token: {
          property: 'access_token',
          maxAge: 60 * 60,
        },
        refreshToken: {
          maxAge: 20160 * 60,
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

и переодически выскакивает

```
HPM] Error occurred while proxying request 127.0.0.1:3080/api/v1/auth/me to https://site.ru/ [ECONNRESET] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

доступ к api у меня https://site.ru/api

Comment: TTL выставлен маленький скорее всего, тухнут токены, а обновлять не обновляете.

Comment: добавил в вопрос настройку auth

Comment: при чем я залогинился и сразу обновил браузер и меня перекидывает на страницу логина